# C++: recursive function for array

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, reverse

I'm trying to write element of array in reverse order and I came across this example

```
template <class T>
void reverse(T arr[], int size)
{
    if (size>=2)
    {
        swap(arr[0],arr[size-1]);
        reverse(arr+1,size-2);
    }       
}
```

I don't get the second line - why are they subtracting the size of the array by 2?
If I have 10 elements in the "swap" function by subtracting it by 1 to swap the first element with the last element then subtracting it again by 2 would give me 8 but putting that size again in the "swap" function I would get 7!! shouldn't it be 8 instead of 7?

Comment: Where do you get 7 from? If `size` is 10, `size - 2` is 8. `size - 1` doesn't modify `size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function works by swapping the first and last elements of the array, then recursively doing the same thing for the sub-array from `[1]` to `[size-2]`, like this (the example assumes an array with 7 elements):

```
|0 1 2 3 4 5 6|  <-- the array as supplied to the function
 6|1 2 3 4 5|0   <-- swap [0] with [6], call recursively for 1..5
 6 5|2 3 4|1 0   <-- swap [1] with [5], call recursively for 2..4
 6 5 4|3|2 1 0   <-- swap [2] with [4], call recursively for 3..3
 6 5 4 3 2 1 0   <-- do nothing because the size is less than 2
```

The size decreases by 2 at each step because 2 elements were swapped and are now in the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is right.
Let's see what is done with a 4-element array : [0,1,2,3]

First call, arr = [0,1,2,3] and size = 4. Size is more than 2, so we swap first and last elements. arr = [3,1,2,0]. Now is the reverse call with arr = [1,2,3] and size = 2.
What is going to be done ? swap(arr[0] *=1*, arr[size-1 *=2-1=1*] *=2*].
The new array is [3,2,1,0].
The second line exclude the last element of the array, which was already done.